# Summing a column based on uniqueness of another column without using temporary table

Tags: mysql, performance, sum, query-performance

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hash` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ndx_hash` (`hash`),
  KEY `hash_and_size_ndx` (`hash`,`size`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This table has files that contains same (`hash`, `size`) with different `name` in it.

It should be noted that two file records containing the same `hash` will have the same `size`.

What I'm looking for is the total size of unique files in this table. Uniqueness is based on `hash` column.

Here is a query that provides what I want:

```
SELECT sum(t.unique_size) FROM (SELECT MIN(size) as unique_size FROM files GROUP BY hash) AS t;
```

Output is:

```
+--------------------+
| sum(t.unique_size) |
+--------------------+
|           64233241 |
+--------------------+
```

The reason I don't like this query is because its slow. Its slow because it creates a temporary table. My table has more than 5m records in it.

I think it is a waste to create a giant temporary table since it is theoretically possible to allocate one integer field and increment it as the `unique_size`'s (see my query) are generated.

Is there a way to get what I want without creating a temporary table?

Note: I've experimented `WITH ROLLUP` and found no use of it.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is or what your desired output looks like.  Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: @MichaelGreen I've added that information.

Comment: I suggest you add an index on `(hash,size)` and test again.

Comment: @ypercube I already have that index on my production table, updated the question.

Comment: How many different `hash` values are there on the table?

Comment: @ypercube around 2.5m

Comment: Try making the size column in the hash/size index DESC

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest normalizing data and splitting the table into the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `file_data` (
`data_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`hash` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`size` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`data_id`),
UNIQUE (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `file_names` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (data_id) REFERENCES file_data(data_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This eliminates the possibility of inconsistency between `hash` and `size` fields, and the total size of all (unique) files can be obtained with the query:

```
select sum(size) from file_data;
```

If you need the original (denormalized) structure, you can perform a simple `join`:

```
select id, name, hash, size 
from file_names n join file_data d on d.data_id = n.data_id;
```